# Align normal text inside a listing

Tags: listings, vertical-alignment

I need a way to correctly align the escaped strings that I put inside of this listing. The problem is that they are presented right aligned. I want that this lines keep the indentation of the previous code. For example:

```
 line of code 
 line of code
        line of code
        \vdots correctly aligned escaped string
```

what I have is something like

```
 line of code 
 line of code
        line of code
                           \vdots right aligned escaped string
```

the real code is this:

```
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,,basicstyle=\footnotesize, showspaces=false,showtabs=false,,breaklines=true,showstringspaces=false,breakatwhitespace=true,frame=trBL, escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string oldName;
        int index = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listView1.LabelEdit = true;
            listView1.MultiSelect = false;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add("xd"+index);
            index++;
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
            (*@  $\vdots$ @*)
            (*@  $\vdots$ Comparaciones similares a la anterior. Compactadas por brevedad. @*)
            (*@  $\vdots$ @*)

        }
```

Comment: While it is good that you include some code, it is much better to include a minimal working example---a complete chunk of code that can be copied and compiled and which exhibits your issue whilst containing nothing not needed to do so.

Comment: add the documentclass and begin{document} and end{document} to the code that i expose.

Comment: Yes, I and everyone else who might try to help you could each take a few seconds to do that. Or, you, the person seeking help, could take a few seconds to do that for all of those who might help you. One alternative is both much more efficient and polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce what you're seeing with the following minimal example (though the line breaks on the frame are weird). There's probably another package you're using that's causing the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,,basicstyle=\footnotesize, showspaces=false,showtabs=false,,breaklines=true,showstringspaces=false,breakatwhitespace=true,frame=trBL, escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string oldName;
        int index = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listView1.LabelEdit = true;
            listView1.MultiSelect = false;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add("xd"+index);
            index++;
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
            (*@  $\vdots$ @*)
            (*@  $\vdots$ Comparaciones similares a la anterior. Compactadas por brevedad. @*)
            (*@  $\vdots$ @*)

        }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are right the problem with the alignment was with the tabs characters. I don't know why but if i use tabs instead of spaces i get the bad result, i.e the text right aligned, if i use spaces then i get the result that you expose. Weird thing. Can you give me some hints to avoid break the external box?