# add vdots to a listing without breaking the box

Tags: listings, boxes

I have a problem when I try to add `\vdots` in an escaped string inside of a `listing` environment. The box is cut. How can I avoid the break of the box?

The code is this:

```
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,,basicstyle=\footnotesize, showspaces=false,showtabs=false,,breaklines=true,showstringspaces=false,breakatwhitespace=true,frame=trBL, escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
            textBox1.Text = doc.Descendants("dos").Single().Value.Replace("\n","\r\n");
            int val = textBox1.Lines.Count();
            (*@{\center\vdots}@*)
            XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
            doc2.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
            textBox2.Text = doc2.GetElementsByTagName("dos")[0].InnerText;
        }
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Could you please point out how this differs from your last question [Align normal text inside a listing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/align-normal-text-inside-a-listing). I have difficulties seeing the difference.

Comment: @MartinScharrer they differs in that they are completely different questions, :D. Using similar code snippet do not imply that the questions are the same.

Comment: @voodoomsr: Both questions are about how to get `\vdots` in a listing and could easily asked as one question. Some other things: Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, not just a code fragment. Also please capitalize your sentences and the title. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinScharrer again martin read the questions, they are semantically different, ok they share code but they are just different. I try to avoid adding the \documentclass and \begin and \end{document} when they are basic, because everyone understand that sentences are needed, so it is a unnecessary overload.

Comment: @voodoomsr: As said, both could be asked as one question, but if you want to split them into two than it is also OK. People like to compile your code and their solutions. If you don't add the surrounding code **EVERYONE** which wants to help you **has to do that** which is the **true overhead**. Also often (but not here) issues are caused by different seemly unrelated packages. Without seeing the full code it is often very hard to help people.

Comment: @MartinScharrer point taken. In my following questions i'm going to add that lines to avoid people get confuse in package's uses.

Comment: Is there a solution for `\lstinputlisting`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`\raisebox`](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#raisebox) with its two optional arguments to set the official height and depth to zero to avoid the extra vertical spacing which rips the frame open. You can also adjust the vertical position to make the dots be appear vertical centered as well. The horizontal centering can be done using `\centerline` (or with `\hfill <code> \hfill\null`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,,basicstyle=\footnotesize, showspaces=false,showtabs=false,,breaklines=true,showstringspaces=false,breakatwhitespace=true,frame=trBL, escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
    textBox1.Text = doc.Descendants("dos").Single().Value.Replace("\n","\r\n");
    int val = textBox1.Lines.Count();
(*@\centerline{\raisebox{-1pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\vdots$}}@*)
    XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
    doc2.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
    textBox2.Text = doc2.GetElementsByTagName("dos")[0].InnerText;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

(I removed the spaces in front of the listing because the will push the code to much to the right)

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `\center`, it's wrongly used.

You can just escape the symbol, and be sure it is not too tall.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,,basicstyle=\footnotesize, showspaces=false,showtabs=false,,breaklines=true,showstringspaces=false,breakatwhitespace=true,frame=trBL, escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
            textBox1.Text = doc.Descendants("dos").Single().Value.Replace("\n","\r\n");
            int val = textBox1.Lines.Count();
(*@\makebox[\linewidth][c]{$\smash{\vdots}$}@*)
            XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
            doc2.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
            textBox2.Text = doc2.GetElementsByTagName("dos")[0].InnerText;
        }
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @LeoLiu that is almost what i need, but it is not centered. Is there a way to put that dots in the middle?

Comment: @voodoomsr: Martin's solution is OK. There're also some other solutions, I updated the answer to give another valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

use it this way:

```
(*@{\hspace*{3cm}\vdots}@*)
```

Comment: that sentence also break the box